# Android taking in information from text fields and entering into website for login

Tags: android, eclipse

I was trying to create an app that simply integrates the user to facebook or twitter.

The following code connects the user with facebook

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now my question is,  I would like to show the user two text areas where they put in there username and password and then send them to the facebook login screen and log the person in without ever seeing the login screen.

If anyone knows how to do this or knows where there is a good tutorial on doing it, the help would be appreciated.

I know facebook and twitter have apps I am only using them as examples for learning purposes.

Also if I were to change the link to just say a site that once you logged in you had could view pdfs.  How would I make the pdf viewable in that screen without having to download it?

Answer (score 2):

You could always create a proxy page that submits a request to Facebook's login page. Your page could look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect() {
        document.forms["frmRedirect"].submit(); 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="redirect();">
<form name="frmRedirect" action="https://www.facebook.com/login.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="<USERNAME>" />
<input type="hidden" type="password" name="pass" id="pass" value="<PASSWORD>" />
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not believe Facebook has any query string values you can pass username and password to and I'm not sure if the Android SDK has any web request APIs. If they do, then you're probably better off using those. With your own proxy page like the above though you have full control over the request. If the username and password are dynamic like they are in your situation you can easily modify the above code so it also includes support for query string values. You'd then modify the onload function to read these query string values and insert their values into the email and pass fields.

Once you've done all this, you just open your proxy page from your android app instead of facebook directly.

Also, depending on what you're end result is you may want to read up on their documentation. http://developers.facebook.com/